# Getting error while trying to loading a react-leaflet map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to load the leaflet map but it is giving me an error: 
`Attempted import error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap').`

I tried to install react-leaflet again and also tried to import `leaflet/dist/leaflet.css` in my App.js file but it is still showing me the error. Here is the code 
**Map.js**

```
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./Map.css";

function Maps({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Maps;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css'
import Maps from './Maps'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

function App() {
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({ lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796})
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3)

return (
    <div className="app">
        <Maps
            center= {mapCenter}
            zoom= {mapZoom}
         />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not using the correct version of react-leaflet (yours do not export Map).
See my working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-forked-mg8x4?file=/src/index.js. I used 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a size to your Map, maybe the problem comes from there

```js
   <Map
       style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
       center={position}
       zoom={zoom}
   >
```

Comment: sorry but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You imported your components incorrectly.
If you are using react-leaflet 2.x.x  you need to import Map as in this example below.
If you use react-leaflet 3.0.5 there are several changes.
I made an example with the last react-leaflet in this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-305-4cyeg?file=/src/Map.js).

**Map.js**

```js
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./Map.css";

function Maps({ center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <Map center={center} zoom={zoom}
      {/* Give your map a size */}
      style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
        >
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Maps;
```

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css'
import Maps from './Maps'

function App() {
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({ lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796})
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3)

return (
    <div className="app">
        <Maps
            center= {mapCenter}
            zoom= {mapZoom}
         />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```